# How do I get all 3d points in a numpy array that are not within a inner bounding box, but between the outer bounding box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, point-clouds, bounding-box

I have a Numpy array for 3d points in the format (n, 3), where n is the number of points, and column 1 is the x coordinate, column 2, is the y coordinate, and column 3 is the z coordinate. How do I get all the point in the outer bounding box, but not in a inner bounding box?

Comment: Please provide code and attempt.

Comment: @pygeek . I have code for finding the points in the bounding box. Here is the link. gist.github.com/stanleyshly/4a72886a5ae2d8d324b7d2859d7c4fcf. However, my approach used to be find all points in the inner box, then outer, but that won't work well, since I'm not sure how to find a remove all points in the inner box from the outer box, without using a slow for loop, so could you please help me code this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are the orientations of both boxes? Are the axis parallel to x, y, z?

In this case it is not so difficult.

1. Find out if the point is in the x, y, z range of the outher box
2. if yes: do the same test for the inner box

Just let me know when you need the code

Comment: Yes, the axis are parallel to x,y,z. I have code for finding the points in the bounding box. Here is the link. gist.github.com/stanleyshly/4a72886a5ae2d8d324b7d2859d7c4fcf. However, my approach used to be find all points in the inner box, then outer, but that won't work well, since I'm not sure how to find a remove all points in the inner box from the outer box, without using a slow for loop, so could you please help me code this section?